# PHP MySQL - Detect if missing row in array query

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking up an array of values. Whenever a value in the lookup array is not found in the database, I want to set a value inside the results array to "notFound".

How would I accomplish this?

Code:

```
$sql = "SELECT country FROM customers WHERE name IN ('Adam', 'David', 'Frank', 'Mike')";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $countryArray[] = $row['country'];
    }
}
```

Current output:

```
+----- -+---------+
| Name  | Country |
+------------+----+
| Adam  |      UK | 
| David |      AU | 
| Mike  |      CN | 
+-------+---------+
```

Desired output:

```
+----- -+-------------+
| Name  |     Country |
+------------+--------+
| Adam  |          UK | 
| David |          AU | 
| Frank |     NotFound| 
| Mike  |          CN | 
+-------+-------------+
```

In the example above, if frank is not found in database, I want the result array to return "NotFound".

Comment: Where are you getting `'Adam', 'David', 'Frank', 'Mike'` names? are they in static array

Comment: @urfusion - currently it only returns the country. I just added in those names for clarification.

Comment: If you use the names as keys in your source array, you can set the value to the country in the loop.

Comment: Start with an array of the names. Use `array_fill_keys` to make those names the keys of a new array, and to set the value to `NotFound` at the same time. Then inside your loop, simply overwrite the array element that has the name (select that as well from the database) as key with the country. Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code.

```
$sql = "SELECT name, country FROM customers WHERE name IN ('Adam', 'David', 'Frank', 'Mike')";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$nameArray = array("Adam","David","Frank","Mike");
$dataArray = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $dataArray["Name"][] = $row['name'];
        $dataArray["Country"][$row['name']] = $row['country'];
    }
}

echo 'Name|Country'; 
foreach($nameArray as $val)
{
    echo $val.'|'.((empty($dataArray[$val]))?'Not Found':$dataArray[$val]); 
    // There you can also assign a array for the same.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient/elegant, but should work. Assumes that your `$names` array contains exactly the same names as the DB (case-sensitive).

```
$names = array('Adam', 'David', 'Frank', 'Mike');
$not_found_array = array_fill_keys($names, 'NotFound');

$sql = "SELECT name, country FROM customers WHERE name IN ('".implode("','", $names)."')";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $countryArray[$row['name']] = $row['country'];
    }
}

$countryArray = array_merge($not_found_array, $countryArray);
```